# A stone with the incomplete inscription "IH", how old is it?

Tags: christianity, inscription

I have this stone with the incomplete inscription "IH". I think it could be the [IHS Christogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christogram#IHS) but I am not sure.

The height of the fragment is about 10cm, the material seems terracotta.

The stone was found in a rural area in the Emilia Romagna region in Italy.

A local farmer told me it could be from a cemetery.

What other Latin inscription might it be?

How old is it?

[image: A stone with the incomplete inscription "IH"]

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it will be almost impossible to give a good answer without more background: surely you have some more details to give than just "I have this stone"? The only positive thing I can say is that I don't know any Latin words that begin with IH. IHS is a solid guess, though I see no reason to exclude that this is a Greek inscription.

Comment: @brianpck You're right! I add all the info that I have. Thank you.

Comment: GNOCCHI, perhaps. Or GRACCHI; now that would be fun if you found his brother too.

Comment: @Hugh interesting alternative! Even if I did not understand the joke (?).

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson It's certainly not Gnocchi or Gracchi - so that's the joke - but it could end in -hi. It could well be Italian just as much as Latin or Greek.